# Is my question inappropriate for Academia S.E.?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Next September I will be starting the most important part of my Ph.D in Mathematics: the "go and do something original!" part. To be honest, as someone who never did reseach before, I am a bit scared about it. As I am sure there are many many people in my situation, I would like to ask a question on Academia with the purpose of compiling a list of some of the most important things one can do to increase the chances of succefully going through (and completing) a Ph.D. Of course, I am not looking for general things like "work hard everyday"; ideally, it would be more specific and helpful things.

I am sure that the large experience of the community members would make this possible, and that some valuable tips would certainly arise; but is this question too broad and/ or too opinion-based to fit here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [help center](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

There *are* entire books that (attempt to) answer this question.  For example: Steven Krantz's [*A Mathematician's Survival Guide: Graduate School and Early Career Development*](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=gscm).

Comment: I would say that there are entire books that *address* the question, if you take my meaning.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Good point, I didn't mean to imply that Krantz or anyone else has all the answers.  Edited.

Comment: oh! perhaps this is just the thing I was looking for. thank you!

Answer (score 6):

*In its current form*, I do think this question is too broad/opinion based.

You write

> Of course, I am not looking for general things like "work hard everyday"; ideally, it would be more specific and helpful things.

But in order to avoid answers like that, you need to draft a more specific, focused question.